# Want to show the Stores based on countries

Tags: magento2, redirect, varnish, htaccess, store-switcher

I need to show the stores name like saudi / oman / dubai. Each stores have two store views (Arbic & English).   I want to display these Stores according to their countries. 
For Example Saudi Store will open on saudi with its two store views.

I had tried with GeoIP `.htaccess` file redirection like below,

```
GeoIPEnable On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^SA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is going to the Redirection Loop. I had also tried this [Geo Switch Module](https://github.com/ytorbyk/magento2-geo-store-switcher)  It makes redirection but not allowing another Store view. Also website staring time loading is very slow. I had also tried Amasty Geo IP Extension. It does not supports varnish enabled sites.

I hope `.htaccess` file is the Best way to redirect the sites.

Please Anyone Guide me for this requirement That will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed and enabled mod_geoip in your server for your redirection to work fine?

Comment: @RajMohanR yes i had installed and enabled mod_geoip on my server. While i use htacess file method. site goes in redirection loop due to varnish cache i think. If you have solution please share it to me

Comment: What about this one https://github.com/iwebhosting/varnish-geoip

Comment: @RajMohanR  i will look that module and update here. Is that is enough for varnish cache issue?